# Proving the irreducibility of a polynomial based on its Galois group

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, splitting-field, galois-extensions

Suppose $f(X) \in \mathbb{Q}[X]$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Let $K$ be the splitting field of $f(X)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Prove that if $Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}) \simeq S_n $, then $f(X)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.

How do I prove this claim? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $f=gh$  then $Gal(K/Q)$ is a subgroup of $S_a \times S_b$.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: There is a result of Jordan which says that the Galois group is transitive if and only if the polynomial is irreducible. And $S_n$ is transitive.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh that's not quite precise. Being transitive is a property of a group action, not of a group. For example, there is a transitive embedding of $S_5$ into $S_6$. There are also plenty of non-transitive embeddings. It's true that the action of $S_n$ on the set with $n$ elements is transitive.

Comment: @Mathmo123: I am using this definition: a subgroup $G$ of $S_n$ is transitive if for every pair of positive integers $i, j\in\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ there is a $\sigma\in G$ with $\sigma(i) =j$.